# Move "Continue To Payment" button to top in Woocommerce Checkout

Tags: css, wordpress, woocommerce

I have small issue with the button "Continue To Payment" at checkout into my [Woocommerce page](https://huskypalace.com/product/siberian-husky-adoption-deposit/). I checked with inspect element, and found that button is controled by this CSS:

```
button#place_order.button .fusion-button .button-default .fusion-button-
default-size .alt {
margin-top:-150px !important;
}
```

I inserted this into Custom CSS, but nothing changes. How can I move that button **up** by 150px to top?

Comment: Looking at the page, I see that all classes refer to the button element, not to elements that are inside it, so there should be no spaces between classes to refer to that button.

Comment: Yes that was my problem. Please add as answer so i can accept it. One favor ..Can you help me also with this 900 number to go bellow Total?
https://i.imgur.com/jOexTiu.png?1

Comment: Just add `.woocommerce-Price-amount.amount { float: right }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All classes belong to the button, so they must go without spaces.

```
button#place_order.button.fusion-button.button-default.fusion-button-default-size.alt {
   margin-top:-150px !important;
}
```